# What is different between ObservableList and @observable List in MobX

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I'm a Noob. As the title say What the difference between these three

```dart
ObservableList<Todo> todos;

@observable
ObservableList<Todo> todos;

@observable
List<Todo> todos;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
ObservableList<Todo> todos;
```

This will activate observable only when modifying list, not assigning new one.

```dart
@observable
ObservableList<Todo> todos;
```

This means that both assigning new list to **todos** or modifying todos list would activate observable.

```dart
@observable
List<Todo> todos;
```

This means that observable will be activated every time you make new assignment to **todos** field. Modifying **todo** list will not activate observable.

Answer (score 1):

The list will not notify Mobx that a value has changed when you do:

```
listOfMatches[0] = match;
```

But both will work when you do:

```
listOfMatched = []
```